# CSS: Position absolute with XHTML Transitional Doctype

Tags: css, xhtml, position, doctype

I am trying to position a `<span>` relative to a particular image. I must use the XHTML Transitional doctype because that is what the application has been using since years before I ever laid hands on it and too much depends on it.

The following code correctly positions the `<span>` way off to the side:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.tooltip {
                z-index:1000;

                position:absolute;
                top:200;
                left:600;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="hasTooltip">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
            <span class="tooltip">Tooltip!</span>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this code breaks the `<span>` position, and it always appears in the same spot no matter what the `left` or `top` values are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.tooltip {
                z-index:1000;

                position:absolute;
                top:200;
                left:600;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="hasTooltip">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
            <span class="tooltip">Tooltip!</span>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I correctly position this `<span>` element with the XHTML Transitional doctype?

Comment: Are you sure it's the doctype declaration that's causing issues? I don't believe there's any difference in absolute positioning between standards and almost standards mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `top: 200px` and `left: 600px`. They work in any mode, whereas if you omit `px', it is incorrect CSS code and only works in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html).

Comment: Thank you, I should have noticed that!